# Preprocessing in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm new to python and want to know your ideas on what is the best way to implement the following preprocessing block (which I have implemented using ibm-opl)

What I did in the following code is as follows:

I have created an empty two dimensional matrix known as edu_bg. And I already have a query which provides me number of students in my database table (which I store using stuCount variable) and their education background.
So what I'm doing here is that I compare a pair of students at a time and if their educational background is the same I input them to my two dimensional matrix as one and if they have different educational background I put them as zero.

My code is as follows:

```
    int edu_bg[student][student];

    execute PREPROCESSING{

    for(i=1; i <=stuCount; i++){
      for(j=i+1; j <=stuCount; j++){
       if(stu_info[i].edu==stu_info[j].edu){
          edu_bg[i][j] =1 
           }
       else{
         edu_bg[i][j] =0
           }
       }
   }
```

I tried to do the same using python but I find it really difficult. Because I don't see a clear way to compare student records.

I setup everything to connect with database and fetching records using python as follows:

```
    con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join('..','db_path', 'db'))
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select id,edu from student_data') 
    result = cur.fetchall()
    for i in result:
       print i[0]
```

Ok. When i print i[0] it gives me all the id's of students. When I print i[1] it gives me student's education details (In my databse I store it as an integer ex: 11, 22. but my problem is how to compare a pair of students based on their education. My question here is on data structures. Am I in the correct path ?

Comment: The code in Python would be almost the same as the one here, with different syntax for loops and similar details. The only difficult thing, if I understand you correctly, is implementing `stu_info[i].edu==stu_info[j].edu`. But we don't see here what `stu_info` is at all. And we don't see what you tried in python. The python code here is not at all related to the other code.

Comment: Sorry I have not clearly explained stu_info[i].edu==stu_info[j].edu. It is actually how I fetched education details of a student using ibm-opl. For instance stu_info [i].edu return the educational background (which I stored as a code in numbers) of a student.

Comment: The problem is with *"I tried to do the same using python but I find it really difficult"*. Show what you've tried. As it is, it is not clear whether you don't know how to implement comparison, don't know how to use 2d lists, don't know how to implement *for* loops, or don't understand Python syntax at all.There is no way to give an answer without your code.

Comment: Sure. This is what i've been doing so far.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why it's not allowing me to do formatting of the code

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40196114/edit) the question instead of adding to comments ;)

Comment: Thanks. I added the code. But i'm not still progessing. I'm stuck at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort I managed to write the code as follows. Any comments on improvements are welcome.

```
    data=curr.execute('select id,edu from student_data')
    result = curr.fetchall()
    mydic1=dict(result)

    data2=curr.execute('select id,edu from student_data ')
    result2 = curr.fetchall()
    mydic2=dict(result2)

    looping=curr.execute('select count(id) from student_data')
    loop_times = curr.fetchall()
    count = int(loop_times[0][0])

    count = count + 1
    edu=defaultdict(int)
    a=0
    for i in range(1,count):
       row = [] 
       for j in range(i+1, count):
           if mydic1[i]==mydic2[j]:
               row.append(1)
           else:
             row.append(0)
           edu[a]=row
           a+=1
      print edu
```